# Why should I specify Spring context in IntelliJ IDEA manually?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

IDEA IDE always asks to configure context for its xml files manually... What difficulties are connected with this issue, why it's not done automatically?

Comment: You can have many xml files, some for testing, some for specific environments, there might be a hierarchy between the xml (parent context, child context). The IDE cannot figure this out on its own.

Comment: @M.Deinum I think it answers my question, make this comment an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Spring you can have multiple files making up 1 or more application contexts. It could be a mix of xml, properties and java based configuration.

It is also possible that there is a hierarchy in your `ApplicationContext`s or that you want to specify a different configuration for a certain environment.

An IDE cannot figure all this out on its own and therefor will leave the exact configuration of the contexts and the context hierarchy to you the developer.